# Pointer events are not firing when HubSection Manipulation mode is set to System

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

Even the CoreWindow doesn't receive any events in that case (on WinPhone device or emulator). How I can track pointer position and state if PointerMoved doesn't firing? I've added handlers to CoreWindow, page - no matter. I've used AddHandler with last parameter set to "true" - it doesn't change things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get this behaviour any time you have a ScrollViewer either directly or within a control (most collection controls contain a ScrollViewer, including the Hub). When the ScrollViewer receives the PointerPressed event it takes over the pointer handling to run its scrolling, and once the ScrollViewer is in charge it handles all of the pointer and manipulation events without the app having its own chance at them.

There isn't a way to avoid this once the ScrollViewer has taken over the manipulations. Depending on the app's specific needs it may be able to prevent the ScrollViewer from handling the manipulations so the app can do so itself, but there isn't a good way for an app to both let the ScrollViewer scroll and to handle the pointer messages.

I wrote a blog entry about this in the Windows 8 timeframe: [Where did all my gestures go?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2013/02/16/where-did-all-my-gestures-go.aspx) There were a few updates to this behaviour for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, but the basic concepts are still valid.